# how can i create index without restart sphinx searchd serivice

Tags: php, sphinx

I m new in sphinx search.i have installed sphinx in windows 7 .

My question is how can i create new index in sphinx without start-stop searchd service ?

Because Every time when i create a new index and then run query in php script it will display error unknown local index.

Is it necessary to stop searchd when indexing ?

I really appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have admin right for start and stop the searchd services.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the --rotate switch with indexer. That should tell indexer to tell the Sphinx Service to reload and find new indexes.

Comment: Yes i have use the rotate switch but it gives following warning :indices NOT rotated?

Comment: Does --rotate work when you are just updating an existing index?

Comment: Make sure you have 2.0.6 , older versions can't add new indexes with --rotate only

Comment: i have 2.0.5 version.am i need an admin rights to use sphinx?